# How to extract data from multiple csv files and place the data into one common table? [Matlab]

Tags: matlab, csv

I have five different .csv files that I need to extract data from, and after I extract the data from each one i'd like to place this data into a table.

My .csv directory:

```
2015.csv
2014.csv
2013.csv
2012.csv
2011.csv
```

My attempt at doing this is:

```
csvfiles = dir('.../*.csv');
dataArray = {}
table = table(dataArray{1:end-1}, 'VariableNames', {'WEEK','2015','2014', '2013', '2012', '2011'});

for file = csvfiles
      delimiter = ',';
      startRow = 2;
      formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%[^\n\r]';

      fileID = fopen(file,'r'); % 
      dataArray = {dataArray, textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false)};
      fclose(fileID);
      extracting_data = file.column1 + file.column3
end
```

However, not only does the fileID take an invalid argument `file`, but i'm not sure how to extract the data and store it in the table. I can make the fileID valid by using `file(1).name`, but then `textscan()` throws an error saying `Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to
generate a valid file identifier.`.

Basically, my goal is:

```
1. Open each file in the directory.
2. Extract all necessary data from the known columns
3. Put all 52 values inside that file into their own column (one column per file).
```

**EDIT 1:**
Here is an update of my code. I changed the data structure of `dataArray` to a matrix.

```
csvfiles = dir('/.../Data/*.csv');
data_matrix = zeros(52, 5);    % Create empty matrix and format the matrix like the table.
iter = 0;

for file = 1:numel(csvfiles)
    iter = iter + 1;
    delimiter = ',';
    startRow = 2;
    formatSpec = '%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%f%[^\n\r]';

    fileID = fopen(csvfiles(file).name,'r');
    data = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'HeaderLines' ,startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false);
    fclose(fileID);

    extracted_data = file.column1 + file.column2;    % I make sure to use the column headers.

    % Add all 52 values from the extracted data to a single column.
    data_matrix[:,iter] = influenza_a;
end


%% Create output table.
Influenza = table(data_matrix{1:end-1}, 'VariableNames',{'WEEK','2015','2014','2013','2012','2011'});
```

Comment: Change `for file = csvfiles` to `for file = 1:numel(csvfiles)` and `fileID = fopen(csvfiles(file),'r');` that should be the first fix

Comment: @Adriaan I got an error saying `First input must be a file name of type char, or a file
identifier of type double.` for the `fopen()` line. When I `disp(csvfiles(file))` it returns `name, date, bytes, isdir, datenum`.

Comment: Did you change the `fopen` line like I said in my previous comment? So not in the `for` line, I was a bit short. Change `fileID = fopen(file,'r');` to `fileID = fopen(csvfiles(file),'r');`, in addition to the change in the `for` loop I suggested earlier

Comment: Yes, I changed both the for loop and the `fopen` line.

Comment: `csvfiles(file)` is a struct containing some information, including the name. You to pass only the name: `fileID = fopen(csvfiles(file).name,'r');`

Comment: Fixed. I was almost there, I was playing around with `fopen(csvfiles(file.name));`. However, `textscan` seems to still not be accepting the struct `file`.

Comment: @Daniel interesting. I've never seen that in my `dir` calls. Was that introduced after 2012a? I'm used to it providing only a list of file names.

Comment: @Adriaan: `dir` prints only the filenames when called without an output argument, but it returns a struct. This is the behaviour of `dir` at least since [R13](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R13sp2/techdoc/matlab.html) (Year 2002)

Comment: @Hunter: What error do you get from `textscan`? Is `fileID` larger than zero? (-1 indicates an error when opening the file).

Comment: `textscan` throws `Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file
identifier.`. And yes, `fileID` appears to be `-1`. I've also edited the original post to show what my code looks like now. I've changed the data structure of the exported data, and moved a few things around.

Comment: I noticed another problem with your code, the first line probably should list the files in the parent directory? This would be `csvfiles = dir('../*.csv');`, I am not aware of any OS using three dots but I could be wrong here. As you index the parent directory, your filename `fullfile('..',csvfiles(file).name)`, the `..` must be included as well when opening the file.

Comment: Sorry about that, no I do indeed specify the entire parent directory. I only used three dots for brevity.

Comment: Parent directory is two dots. On my system three dots did not return anything so I was not sure about that code line. I will write an answer which hopefully collects everything.

Comment: Oh, two dots means the parent directory? I wasn't aware of that. On the file i'm working with I specify the parent directory like so `/Users/user/folder/folder/MATLAB/folder/Data/*.csv'`. I was only using three dots on this post to prevent from having to write all of it out. And thanks tremendously for the help from both you and Adriaan. Edit: two dots doesn't work on my OS (mac)

Comment: If you want to understand the `..` you could read some introduction about relative paths, but it seems unnecessary in this case. I simply misinterpreted your placeholder `...`  as a typo of `..`